# Grey screen while booting Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi 4B 4G

Tags: boot, system-installation, raspberrypi

With the release of the new Raspberry Pi 4B I thought it was time I picked one up, so I bought one and loaded Raspbian onto it no problem and played around for a bit but I read Ubuntu just released an OS that supported Pi 4.

The problem I am having is the initial install, Balena Etcher has an error preventing it from working on mac-OS Catalina so I had to create the bootable micro SD using the terminal (there were plenty of tutorials on how to do it) however when I boot the pie, it starts to boot (raspberry logo, text running down the screen) then it goes to a blank screen as if just the LED back-light is on and displays nothing.

What I have tried since:

- I have tried both the 64 and 32 bit image files
- I have tried turning on and off the PI a couple times
- I have tried leaving the pie until the green LED stopped flashing

I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong with the creation of the bootable drive or if maybe its just a problem with the image file since it has only recently been released.

These are the two ways I used to create bootable drives:

1

`xz -d ubuntu.img.xz` then

`sudo dd bs=1m if=~/Downloads/ubuntu.img of=/dev/rdisk2 conv=sync`

2

`xzcat ~/Downloads/ubuntu.img.xz | sudo dd of=/dev/disk2 bs=32m`

If someone has had this problem or knows how to solve it that would be greatly appreciated.

What I am using:

- Raspberry Pi 4B 4GRAM Model
- 64GB Samsung Micro SD card
- 2014 Macbook Pro (used to create bootable drives)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which image are you trying to write?

Comment: I have tried both 32bit and 64bit