# Never displayed when installing Ubuntu 19.10 for Raspberry Pi 4B 4G

Tags: boot, system-installation, raspberrypi, 19.10

I tried installinging Ubuntu 19.10 on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, but it displayed nothing on the monitor.

I downloaded both server images on
https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/raspberry-pi

then flashed 
32bit

```
ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz
```

and 64bit

```
ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz
```

by using balenaEtcher.

- I have tried both the 64 and 32 bit image files
- I have tried turning on and off the PI a couple times
- I have tried using another Micro SD card
- I could install Raspbian buster (all environments were same)

My environments are

- Raspberry Pi 4B 4GRAM Model
- 64GB SanDisk Micro SD card (it works when I flashed Raspbian
- MacBook Pro Early 2013

And this question seems like this one.
[Grey screen while booting Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi 4B 4G](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182868/)

Answer (score 1):

Is the HDMI port connected to a monitor or TV?
Do you use an HDMI switch connected to the monitor?
Make sure that during installation there is only active direct raspberry-monitor connection.

I have installed the 32 bit Ubuntu 19.10 version on my raspberry Pi 4 4GB with overclocking CPU at 2 GHz and GPU at 650 MHz, and it works very well.

1. You need to download the Ubuntu 19.10 32-bit server image (`ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-armhf` + `raspi3.img.xz`) from https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi.
2. Download the BalenaEtcher application compatible with your operating system and use this utility to write the image on your microSD
   from https://www.balena.io/etcher/.
3. Once the microSD is ready, open the file /boot/config.txt with `vim` (if you use windows you can use `notepad++`) and add it at the end of the file:

   ```
   over_voltage=4
   arm_freq=2000
   gpu_freq=650
   ```
4. Insert your microSD in the raspberry and start the system. Once you get to the login, enter the username and password credentials = `ubuntu`.

   The system will ask you to change your password.

   At this point you can install the desktop version of ubuntu you want with the command: (make sure the raspberry is connected to the internet for example with the ethernet cable)

   ```
   sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop
   ```
5. After installation, restart the system:

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my Raspberry Pi 4. I ended up following the Windows section of this [article](https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/installation-media).

I installed the 64 bit version of Ubuntu Server from this [page](https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/raspberry-pi).

I used 7-Zip UI to unzip the file and then used balenaEtcher to put the image on my 64GB microSD card. For some reason, on first boot it did not work. I powered off the pi and powered it back on and it worked (it might have had to do with my monitor not showing the output the first time).